# Extracting tar.xz won't output file PHP

Tags: php, tar, shell-exec, xz

I have a file called `control.tar.xz`. I'm trying to extract the file, but there is no output.

Heres my code:

```
shell_exec('cd ' . __DIR__ . ' && tar -xf control.tar.xz');
```

I'm checking for `control` and it's not showing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest to add `-J` to your GNU tar command. See: `man tar`

Comment: @Cyrus `shell_exec('cd ' . __DIR__ . ' && tar -xf -J control.tar.xz')` Like this? It's outputting the same thing.

Comment: The `-f` option must be followed by the file name.

Comment: Okay, I changed it to `tar -J -xf control.tar.xz`. I tested it on my computer and it worked, but it didnt work in the script.

Comment: Is control.tar.xz unpacked?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting this command to DO?

Comment: @Cyrus The script isn't unpacking the file. I checked my project directory after running it and `control.tar.xz` was still there, and `control` wasn't added.

Comment: @Sammitch Im trying to unpack a `control.tar.xz` file.